# Can you change pokemons during a Gym Battle?

Tags: pokemon-go

If the second pokemon in a Gym is Super effective against me, can I change pokemons or do I have to die as much times as it takes for me to get to a pokemon that will defeat or be super effective against the pokemon in the gym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. Just type the button in the bottom right during a fight:

[image: poke_gym_fight]

Comment: Oh, never saw that there was a button there lol.

Comment: Matter that you are supposed to change the Pokémon quickly since the fight isn't stopped during the change menu.